# Shorten include in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

How to shorten when including module in rails model. Below is my sample code.

Can i write it in one line like this?

```
class TableName < ActiveRecord::Base < ModelRelationConcern::JoinChair
```

But I'm getting the following error.

```
superclass must be a Class (NilClass given)
```

I think the one I am calling is extend, not sure if it was.

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: do you realize what you really are doing? :)

Comment: i just want to make this line of code shorter, what i mean 1 liner.class TableName < ActiveRecord::Base include ModelRelationConcern::JoinChair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comment added to the question I understood it. The answer is **No**. Including a module is not equal inheritance, so you can't write it in one line.

You can reopen `ActiveRecord::Base` in a separate file and `include` your module there, so that you won't need to do it in model. But in anyway you have to include it somewhere.

P.S. You, of course, could write it as follows:

```
class TableName < ActiveRecord::Base; include ModelRelationConcern::JoinChair end
```

It is nominally a oneline, but technically it's not and it is also not conventional to write so.

Comment: So much appreciated. Thanks a lot @Andrey Deineko.

Comment: @Lymuel, you're welcome. Please accept the answer (checkmark on the left side of it) if that was helpful